# How To Add Sorting Ascending And Descending Order in custom attribute of customer grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, grid, customer-grid

I Created the Customer Custom Attribute using Upgrade Schema Like This

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $sortOrder = 200;
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0) {
            //$this->_addCustomerAttributeGroup($setup, "Spire Attributes");
            $attributes1 = [
                'customer_id'   =>  'Spire Customer ID',
                'customer_name' =>  'Customer Name',
                'currency'      =>  'Currency',
                'present_bal'   =>  'A/R Balance',
                'credit_line'   =>  'Credit Limit $',
                'disc_pct'      =>  'Discount %',
                'dflt_ship_to'  =>  'Default Ship-To Address',
                'term_code'     =>  'Terms Code',
                'user_type'     =>  'Spire User Type',
                'special_handling'  =>  'Special Handling',
                'discount_code'     =>  'Spire Discount Code',
                'customer_number'   =>  'Customer Number',
                'currency_id'       =>  'Currency Id',
                'currency_code'     =>  'Currency Code',
                'currency_description'  =>  'Currency Description',
                'term_description'  => 'Terms Description',
                'notes'  => 'Spire Notes'
            ];
            foreach($attributes1 as $attributeCode => $attributeLabel) {
                $this->_addCustomerAttributeTypeText($setup, $attributeCode, $attributeLabel, $sortOrder);
                $sortOrder++;
            }
            $attributes2 = [
                'spire_mod_date'     => 'Spire Modified Date',
                'spire_created_date' => 'Spire Created Date',
            ];
            foreach($attributes2 as $attributeCode => $attributeLabel) {
                $this->_addCustomerAttributeTypeDate($setup, $attributeCode, $attributeLabel, $sortOrder);
                $sortOrder++;
            }
```

> They Edit From Admin Like This

[image]

> And Using Customer Grid I add That Custom Attribute in customer Grid
> Like That my custome_listing.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="customer_id" class="Vwndor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SpireCustomerId">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                     <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Spire Customer Id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>


    </columns>
</listing>
```

> my Data source file is

```
/**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
   public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $customer  = $this->_customerRepository->getById($item["entity_id"]);
                $spire_id = $customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_id');
                if (!is_null($spire_id) && $spire_id->getValue()) {
                    $item['customer_id'] = $spire_id->getValue(); 
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
```

> the Admin Grid Show Like This

[image]

> In that shorting not working when i apply sorting they throw exception
> error like this

```
LIMIT 20 {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_id' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT main_table.*, IFNULL(rnt.name, IFNULL(rct.default_name, main_table.billing_region)) AS billing_region FROM customer_grid_flat AS main_table LEFT JOIN directory_country_region AS rct ON rct.region_id=main_table.billing_region_id LEFT JOIN directory_country_region_name AS rnt ON rnt.region_id=main_table.billing_region_id AND rnt.locale='en_US' ORDER BY customer_id ASC LIMIT 20 at /var/www/html/unobstructedview/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_id' in 'order clause' at /var/www/html/unobstructedview/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []
```

Answer (score 0):

Your customer attribute column not added in the "customer_grid_flat" table

Comment: in witch table i need to add this ??

Comment: how can i apply this without add column in customer_grid_flat